# How does stackoverflow creates the unique number for questions?

Tags: database, unique

I was just curious how stackoverflow creates the unique numbers for questions. I am doing something similar and I was curious which way will be better. Are they just using the auto increment on the database or some kind of random unique number generator? What will be the pros and cons of doing those ways ? I totally understand the question is little vague but I am just wanting to know the opinion from experts.

Comment: Perhaps this should be on meta?

Comment: I don't know how Stack Overflow does it.  But a place to start in understanding the methods is with Bloom Filters . . . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Approximating_the_number_of_items_in_a_Bloom_filter.

Comment: Here is a [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) of SE data. Figure it out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you application you can use GUID: Globally unique identifier.

Comment: Yes and then thanks to them you can change the URL and access corresponding data (Questions in this example)